# Call to CFURLCreateFromFileSystemRepresentation sometimes fails

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, core-foundation

I have an application that loads in a bundle and in doing so I call **CFURLCreateFromFileSystemRepresentation** before CFBundleCreate: -

```
bundlePackageURL = CFURLCreateFromFileSystemRepresentation(
           kCFAllocatorDefault,
           (const UInt8*)bundlePackageFileSystemRepresentation,
           strlen(bundlePackageFileSystemRepresentation),
           true );
```

Most of the time, running the same application and loading the same bundle that resides in the application bundle's Resource directory, the function works and returns a valid CFURL. However, with exactly the same parameters passed in to the function, the call sometimes fails.

I now have code to handle the failure: -

```
    CFURLRef bundlePackageURL = NULL;
    int attempt = 0;        
    while((bundlePackageURL == NULL) && (attempt++ < 12000))
    {
        bundlePackageURL = CFURLCreateFromFileSystemRepresentation(
           kCFAllocatorDefault,
           (const UInt8*)bundlePackageFileSystemRepresentation,
           strlen(bundlePackageFileSystemRepresentation),
           true );

        // failed to load, so try again
        if(bundlePackageURL == NULL)
            fprintf(stdout, "Retrying to obtain CFURL: %d...\n", attempt);
    }
```

As you can see, this makes up to 12000 attempts to call the function and when it fails, I've seen it take anything between a few hundred to over 10000 repeated calls before it succeeds.

Can anyone please explain why the function may be failing at times and if this is normal?

Comment: Yes, seeing the same problem but on much fewer calls (< 200). I get error -10 ("unknown error") returned. Did you ever get to the bottom of this issue?

Comment: No, I just keep calling the code, until it returns a valid URL.